# Why does the 3rd image almost skips in this slideshow?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a slideshow in CSS, and it works, BUT...
The 2nd image stays longer than the others, and when it switvhes to the 3rd, it switches right away to the 4th. I don't know what is wrong with my codes, on paper, everything should work fine.

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
        <div id="img1" class="gallery" style="background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7a/d6/80/7ad680c2aeaf6f89496a174c4e0a92db.jpg');"></div>
        <div id="img2" class="gallery" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/69/19/nhvSi4.png');"></div>
        <div id="img3" class="gallery" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.idropnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/26081105/Look-Wide-iPhone-Wallpaper-720x480.jpg');"></div>
        <div id="img4" class="gallery" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.idropnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/23084736/God-is-Real-iPhone-Wallpaper-720x480.jpg');"></div>
        <div id="img5" class="gallery" style="background-image: url('https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/15-154924_m.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow{
    height: 60%;
}

.gallery{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
    height: 60%;
    width: 65%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover; 
}
  
#img1{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: crossfade 25s -0s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
  
#img2{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    animation: crossfade 25s -5s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
  
#img3{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    animation: crossfade 25s -10s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#img4{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    animation: crossfade 25s -15s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#img5{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    animation: crossfade 25s -20s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
  
@keyframes crossfade{
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Side notes: The CSS can be simplified, e.g. `position: absolute` and `animation-timing-function: ease-in-out` can be put in `.gallery` selector.

Comment: Can you check the (file) sizes of the individual images. Maybe one(number 3) is bigger and takes more time to load. Try to load the image3 another time at the end and see if it still needs more time to load. One possibility is your css, but it also might be simply the image files, replace all of them by dummys and see if it still occurs(then its you css).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ombination of z-indexes plus the timing seems to be slightly muddling things - for example it takes 5 seconds to bring an image to full opacity, shows it then another 5 seconds to fade it - so there is overlap in timing between non-adjacent images.

This snippet removes the difference in z-index so all slides are equal in that respect (whether or not you need to set z-index at all is outside the scope of this question as we don't know the full surrounding context). It brings an image in over 2 seconds and takes it out over two seconds so the overlap is just with adjacent slides. It also displaces the starts by anothe 2 seconds so at the very beginning a fully opaque image is shown.

```css
#slideshow {
  height: 60%;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60%;
  width: 65%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: crossfade 25s -2s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: crossfade 25s -7s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#img3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: crossfade 25s -12s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#img4 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: crossfade 25s -17s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#img5 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: crossfade 25s -22s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes crossfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    /* fade in for 2 second */
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
    /* stay fully visible for 3 seconds */
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    /* fade out for 2 second */
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <div id="img1" class="gallery" style="background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7a/d6/80/7ad680c2aeaf6f89496a174c4e0a92db.jpg');"></div>
  <div id="img2" class="gallery" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/69/19/nhvSi4.png');"></div>
  <div id="img3" class="gallery" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.idropnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/26081105/Look-Wide-iPhone-Wallpaper-720x480.jpg');"></div>
  <div id="img4" class="gallery" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.idropnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/23084736/God-is-Real-iPhone-Wallpaper-720x480.jpg');"></div>
  <div id="img5" class="gallery" style="background-image: url('https://www.wallpaperuse.com/wallp/15-154924_m.jpg');"></div>
</div>
```